# Testing private methods in JestJS

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, private-members, nestjs

I am making an API with NestJS (using TypeScript) and it uses JestJS as the default test framework. I am writing a test for a service class and I am trying to access its private functions (Enforced with TypeScript), but I cannot for obvious reasons.

The traditional solution in other languages (like Java) is to change the functions to be in *package* or *internal* scope, but this doesn't exist in TypeScript.

How can I access those functions for testing purposes, but still enforce the private access (as good practice)?

Comment: One solution is to access private properties with bracket, that is `obj['privateMethod']()` However, the private method must be called by a public one, and that's what you should be testing/callinginstead.

Comment: I am testing the public one, but I want to make sure the simple i/o algorithms in the private functions work properly. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a guideline, you should be able to test a class by using its public methods. If there is significant functionality hidden within private/protected access, then it might be a signal that it could be refactored out into another class.

Is it possible for you to refactor the complex private method(s) into another class(es) that you could then test separately?

Please bear in mind that testing your private methods will make your tests more fragile to changes in how you implement the behaviour of the class, even when the behaviour of the class itself hasn't changed. This is highly likely to be the case when refactoring for optimisation, for example.

Edit:
Given that you’re working with JavaScript at the base level, there’s several ways you could achieve your goal, such as the solution you’ve posted making the methods protected and using a subclass to test, or by some variation of making the methods public, temporary or permanently, but it’s almost certainly unwise to do so in any form. I highly recommend reading the following link which provides further information about why it’s a bad idea to do so, and also provides potentially good solutions to the problems you’re having:
https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2017/10/23/unit-testing-private-methods/

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not the question has non-opinionated answers, but I disagree with the idea that this answer should be a comment (it seeks to answer the question, not to further it)

Comment: This may be true, but in my case these actions will never be used outside of the service class (the one I want to test), so making another class isn't a good idea, but I see what you mean. Also, I won't do environment switching, as the examples I've seen are too messy. I will post a good solution that I am using.

Comment: Apart from many good advice here, there is one logical flaw.  Changing something private into public will certainly change its accessibility.   But, if tests are fragile when testing something private, why would they not be fragile any more only by making that same private thing public?

Comment: @dirkhermann It wasn’t my intention to imply that it would be a good idea to do so. I’ve replaced this part with a link describing the anti-pattern here, with some good solutions. Thanks!

Comment: I accepted this answer as it is the better solution. But I also provided a direct answer below that will work for most people. Sometimes you work at a company and your manager asks you to do something and you just do it, even if it is bad practice. I don't want to argue, I just want to get it done, and I'm sure others do too. Thanks.

Comment: @dirkhermann I didn’t properly address your question. The reason the tests will become more fragile is because by testing the private methods we’re testing the internal implementation rather than whether the class functions as expected. If we test private methods and then decide to refactor, we need to rewrite all those tests, which wouldn’t be necessary if we were only testing the public API. Private methods are normally much more open to change than public methods since they’d only affect the class itself and not external consumers

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to make the functions "protected" and extend the class in a class inside the test file, with those functions exposed.

Example:

```
class ClassToTest {
    protected add(x: number, y: number}: number {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

In the test file:

```
class PublicClassToTest extends ClassToTest {
    public add(x: number, y: number): number {
        return super.add(x, y);
    }
}

describe('ClassToTest', () => {

    const obj = new PublicClassToTest();

    it('adding 2 numbers', () => {
        // GIVEN x is 6
        const x = 6;

        // AND y is 2
        const y = 2;

        // WHEN we add them
        const result = obj.add(x, y);

        // THEN the result is 8
        expect(result).toBe(8);
    });
});
```

**As a bonus feature:** This not only solved my issue with this, but also provided a nice way for me to see my function headers from within the test file, without needing to switch back and forth between my test and the class I am testing.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't let you extend a private method in a subclass and make it public

Comment: My mistake! I forgot to say that I made the functions "protected". I updated my answer. Thanks for noticing :)

Comment: The problem is that when someone looks at the class, they are going to think this method is intended to be overridden when it really isn't. I would follow the other suggestions instead. When something isn't easily testable, it's often a sign that it could use some refactoring

Comment: I agree that this is not the perfect solution and that the other is better, but I wanted to provide people with an option that works and would be fine for most cases, like mine. But, in general, I would suggest using the solution in the other answer. I will accept that one instead of mine.